# remove token from wallet - transaction blocked by issuer

Tags: stellar-core, assets, token, trustline, token-wallet

I've got a fishy token in my wallet that I can not remove or send to anybody, because the issuer has blocked my account for sending this asset.

How do I get rid of such assets?
My XLM are blocked and I can not do anything about it.
Sending it back to the issuer also doesn't work.
Feeling highly scammed here...

FYI:
I'm talking about the issuer quantumstellar.ai
(GDGO6TGQLDCUYLQU3JOCSIU7CVCVUC2VHSTUUDPOUEDSZ2L5K3SWO76Y)